# Chain animations of rotation till view is out of window

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I am trying to remove out of display a view but in a manner that appears like spinning a card.
The following does rotate the view out but is not what I am trying to do.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <rotate  
        android:duration="1500"  
        android:fromDegrees="0"   
        android:pivotX="100%"  
        android:pivotY="50%"  
        android:startOffset="0"  
        android:toDegrees="220" />
</set>
```

What I am after is not a rotation per se around a fixed center but a motion similar to throwing a card.
How can I do this?

**Update**
I tried this after answer from @loadedion but is not working:

```
ObjectAnimator rotateAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rootView, "rotation", 0.0f, 360f);  
rotateAnimation.setDuration(5000);  

ObjectAnimator throwAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rootView, "x", rootView.getX(), rootView.getX() + 200);  
throwAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        throwAnimation.setDuration(3000);  
ObjectAnimator throwAnimation2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rootView, "y", rootView.getY(), rootView.getY() + 200);    
throwAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());  
throwAnimation.setDuration(3000);  
AnimatorSet cardThrowAnimations = new AnimatorSet();  
cardThrowAnimations.playSequentially(rotateAnimation, throwAnimation, throwAnimation2);
        cardThrowAnimations.start();
```

Comment: I believe `playSequentially` will wait until each animation is complete before starting the next, so it looks like this would result in the card rotating really slowly for 5 seconds, then move right a little for 3 seconds, then move down a little for three seconds. Is that what you're seeing? Using `playTogether` would run all of the animations at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a view to spin, you have to apply an animation to it.

```
ObjectAnimator rotateAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(targetView, "rotation", 0.0f, 360f);
rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
rotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.RESTART);
rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
rotateAnimation.setDuration(DURATION_ROTATION);
```

And if you want it to slide out like a thrown card while it's rotating, you can create another `ObjectAnimator` to set it's `x` position.

```
ObjectAnimator throwAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(targetView, "x", targetView.getX(), targetView.getX() + 500); // move 500 pixels to the right
throwAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
throwAnimation.setDuration(DURATION_THROW);
```

And then start the animations

```
rotateAnimation.start();
throwAnimation.start();
```

Alternatively, you can also combine them in an `AnimatorSet` to start them together:

```
AnimatorSet cardThrowAnimations = new AnimatorSet();
cardThrowAnimations.playTogether(rotateAnimation, throwAnimation);
cardThrowAnimations.start();
```

Comment: I was thinking that I probably need to use 2 animations but how can I figure out the  X,Y positions of the second animation?

Comment: The START_X_POSITION AND START_Y_POSITION should be deternined by the new position of the view after the first rotations ends right? How?

Comment: @Jim You can position the card view in your layout at the start position of the animation so that you can get the start x,y via `targetPosition.getX()` and `targetPosition.getY()` (make sure to poll the x,y positions after the view has been created)

Comment: Can you see please update in OP?Can't figure out how this works